# Tree - path sum

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Question -> Given a binary tree and a sum, determine if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals the given sum.

My Solution ->

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        if (root == null || sum == 0){
            return false;
        }
        List<Integer> resultSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer result = root.val;
        inorder(root, result, resultSet);
        return resultSet.contains(sum);
    }
    public void inorder(TreeNode root, Integer result, List<Integer> resultSet){
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null){
            resultSet.add(result);
        }
        if (root.left != null) {
            result += Integer.valueOf(root.left.val);
            inorder(root.left, result, resultSet);
        }
        if (root.right != null) {
            result += Integer.valueOf(root.right.val);
            inorder(root.right, result, resultSet);
        }

    }
}
```

Output ->

Input:
[1,-2,-3,1,3,-2,null,-1]
3
Output: true
Expected: false

I am really not sure where I am going wrong with this. I tried playing with the int and Integer type options for result , but it didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is with `result` variable as once you add the value of `left` node to the `result` and are done with the `left` subtree then u will add the value of `right child` to the result, which is wrong as now it is has the sum of both `left` and `right` child value.

So essentially you are adding the values of all the nodes in the `result` that come before 
the node `root` in the `inorder` traversal.

Can you try this:

```
public void inorder(TreeNode root, Integer result, List<Integer> resultSet){
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null){
        resultSet.add(result);
    }
    if (root.left != null) {
        inorder(root.left, result+Integer.valueOf(root.left.val), resultSet);
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        inorder(root.right, result+Integer.valueOf(root.right.val), resultSet);
    }
}
```

EDIT:1

Another simple approach to solve this problem: You don't need to create a array which contains the sum of all the root to leaf paths. You can simply keep decrementing the required sum.

Code:

```
public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return hasPathSumHelper(root, sum);
    }

}

boolean hasPathSumHelper(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {//if leaf node
        if (Integer.valueOf(root.val) == sum) { //if node value is equal to sum
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if ((root.left != null) && (root.right != null)) {
        return (hasPathSumHelper(root.left, sum - Integer.valueOf(root.val)) || hasPathSumHelper(root.right, sum - Integer.valueOf(root.val)));
    }
    if (root.left != null) {
        return hasPathSumHelper(root.left, sum - Integer.valueOf(root.val));
    } else {
        return hasPathSumHelper(root.right, sum - Integer.valueOf(root.val));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey , That didn't work. No , I am not adding the left and child node values at one level. I am going one level deeper by the recursive call and then only adding the result. 
Input:
[7,0,null,-1,-6,null,1,null,null,-7]
0
Output:
false
Expected:
true
So , essentially I am adding the node values only at different levels and then checking whether I have hit a leaf node or not. I used a similar code for finding the different paths in a tree. So thought this approach should work for this question as well .But somewhere I am going wrong.

Comment: I posted another approach to solving this problem. Check that out. Also can you try printing out your result array and see what are the different paths it has. It will help in debugging  the issue with your current approach

Comment: Yes, thanks ! I later tried with a similar approach and it worked .